# How to make dropdown menu in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make a dropdown menu in CSS and seem to have this issue where when I make it, it doesn't show the full dropdown menu. Basically, the dropdown menu gets cut off at the edge of the top navigation bar where it is situated. Below is the code for the dropdown menu and top navigation bar.

**Dropdown menu:**

```
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit; 
  margin: 0; 
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: -1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

**Top Navigation Bar (where the dropdown menu is found:**

```
.topnav {
  background-color: #332B33;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: sticky;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -2px;
}
```

Here is also a link to the website with the issue in question:

https://getgradschooled.com/index.html

The issue is located in the `test` in the top navigation bar. I am trying with a test before including it into the actual navigation options themselves.

Comment: The problem is that your navigation exists within the `.topnav` container, which has `overflow: hidden;` applied to it. This means nothing inside that container can overflow its edges, and that includes your dropdown nav. There's no way around this without removing that rule, but I see that breaks the styling of your header entirely so it likely needs a rething I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to set the 'dropdown-content' class' Z-index to something higher, I reccomend 999.
2. Make it so that the parent div of the dropdown menu has enough room to hold the expanded menu.

Comment: Don't use arbitarily high z-index values if you can help it, that will lead to headaches down the line. Better to [learn how stacking contexts work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context)